# How to use this keyword inside another event handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am displaying a profile image. If that image is bigger than certain dimension I want to scale it so I attach an `onload` event to that image. After the image has loaded I will check whether it is greater and if so then I will scale it to a smaller image. I am displaying a loading animation till the image loads.

```
<td height="203" valign="middle" align="center"><div id="loadingdiv">Loading...
</div><img style="display:none;" id="proimg" src="<?=$path?>" />
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">

var pro = document.getElementById('proimg');
pro.onload = function()
{
    if(this.width>260)this.style.width = '260px';
    if(this.height>200)this.style.height = '200px';
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('loadingdiv').style.display = 'none';
        this.style.display = 'inline';

    },1000);
}

</script>
```

The loading animation will fade and the image will be visible after a second. That is what I want so I did it like the above, but how to refer the this of `onload` into `settimeout` event handler?

Without the `settimeout` it works fine and I can go with that but I just want to show a delay.

**EDIT:**

I use to do like the first reply, but I thought that there should be another way or concept of doing this.

IS THERE ANYTHING I CAN DO WITH CLOSURES HERE? SO THAT I DON'T HAVE TO USE EXTRA VARIABLE REFERENCES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the this keyboard inside an anonymous event handle function, but you can still make a reference of the current this and then use that reference to call the methods/properties on the object. Here's an example :

```
var that = this;
window.setTimeout(function() {
    that.style.display = 'inline';
}, 1000);
```

Comment: this is fine. that is how i do but i thought there would some other option or concept for this. Does Closure have anything to do here? i still have not yet understood closures.

Comment: the problem is that the anonymous function creates a this reference that overwrites the one from the outer scope.

Comment: Is t here any other way other than creating references?